# Подборка фонового изображения случайным образом

Tags: javascript

Итак, у меня такой вопрос: как сделать так, чтобы из определенного списка картинок, функция случайным образом выбирала картинку и ставила ее как фоновое изображение для определенного блока?При перезагрузке страницы,функция снова подбирала случайную картинку. Заранее спасибо)

Answer (score 4):

```
var images = ['http://img715.imageshack.us/img715/8941/xxxxxx.jpg','http://site.ru/logo.png'...];
var num = Math.floor(Math.random()*images.length);
document.getElementById('randomImage').style.backgroundImage='url('+images[num]+")";
```

Должно работать

Comment: Только **images[num-1]**.
Если images.length = 2
и при Math.random() == 1 
то num = 2, а индекс 2 - это 3 элемент.

Comment: Если верить W3Schools, **Math.floor(Math.random()*max);** даст **{0; max-1}**